# Redux Toolkit: lifecycle action types doesn't sync up when dispatching multiple async thunk actions in one thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a async thunk action to orchestrate multiple async thunks like this

```
const someAction = createAsyncThunk(
  'my/someAction',
  async () => {...}
)
const someAction2 = createAsyncThunk(
  'my/someAction2',
  async () => {...}
)
const generatedThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'my/thunk',
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    thunkApi.dispatch(someAction());
    thunkApi.dispatch(someAction2());
  }
)
```

I found out that either one of the async thunk i.e. `someAction` and `someAction` rejected, the `my/thunk` would still be fulfilled. How can I make `my/thunk` rejected when either one of the thunks rejects?

Answer (score 2):

`createAsyncThunk` always catches errors so that we avoid having "uncaught promise rejection" messages in your app.

You would need to check the results of each of those yourself, and return a rejected promise accordingly.

Also, note that as currently written, your code will have both of those thunks running in parallel.  That's fine, just making sure it's what you really want - to run them in serial, you'd need to `await` them.

One option here would be:

```js
return Promise.all([
  thunkApi.dispatch(someAction()).then(unwrapResult),
  thunkApi.dispatch(someAction2()).then(unwrapResult)
]);
```

That will:

- Run both actions in parallel
- Convert each action's result action back into a fulfilled or rejected promise
- Return a promise that will reject if either of those requests rejected

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! Actually `someAction` and `someAction2` are not in parallel, `someAction2` will only execute when there is a certain error happening during `someAction` , I greatly simplify the code so it looks like they are parallel. If we only look at either one of them here, as I was asking, I want `'my/thunk'` rejects when `'my/someAction' or `my/someAction2` rejects, I need to return a promise that will reject. I wonder if you could add a code snippet in your answer to show me how to do that? thanks!

Comment: btw as you said if I have to run these actions in serial, I need to `await`. I wonder if there is any other ways which use the static methods on `Promise` like `Promise.all`(I know `Promise.all` doesn't work in this case)

Answer (score -1):

Check your child action result and simply `throw` a `new Error` there, your main action automatically catch this. And will be ended in `reject`.

Ex:
[image]

or if your types are correctly configured you can destruct the error object and do a check whit the error like this:
`if(error) throw Error('Some message!')`;

Comment: the child action returns a promise, when the promise resolves the child action will be `fulfilled` and when the promise rejects the action will be `rejected`

Comment: You need to use `await` or your main action doesn't wait for his child action and does a return before the child action will be fulfilled or rejected.

Comment: I tried to `await` the child actions but still didn't get `rejected` for the main action when the child action rejected. My child action is really just like this `export const action = createAsyncThunk("action",async () => {
  return Promise.reject("reject");
}`. But `unwrapResult` does solve the problem